# How to pass data in angular-fancy-modal?

Tags: angularjs

I am using [angular-fancy-modal](https://github.com/vesparny/angular-fancy-modal) to display modals in my app.

This is my controller:

```
.controller('CategoryController', ['$scope', 'categoryService', '$fancyModal', function($scope, categoryService, $fancyModal) {
  $scope.subcategories = {};

  $scope.open = function() {
    $fancyModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'public/popupTmpl.html',
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $scope.subcategories;
        }
      }
    });
  };
}]);
```

The method `ng-click` calls method `$open`.

popupTmpl.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="popupTmpl.html">
  <div class="modal-header"> $$items$$
    <div class="categories-list">
      <span class="list-category-item">100</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

In template: `popupTmpl.html` I tried to get `items` from `resolve`, but it does not work. How to pass data `$scope.subcategories` in template?

Comment: Can you also post your main HTML and the `popupTmpl.html`?

Comment: Yes, look my templte is: ` <script type="text/ng-template" id="popupTmpl.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                $$items$$
                <div class="categories-list">
                    <span class="list-category-item">100</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>`

Comment: What is ```$$items```? Do you have ```$$``` set up in your $interpolateProvider? Also you specified the templateUrl as 'public/popupTmpl.html' however you have the id set to 'popupTmpl.html' in your markup.

Comment: Yes, I posted in question

Comment: Yes, I use `$$` in `$interpolateProvider`

Comment: You're using `public/popupTmpl.html` as templateUrl, but your template ID is popupTmpl.html. Also, your subcategories is an empty object. And the method is not $open, but open. Please post a real, complete, minimal example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr for example. Also you haven't posted the controller of the modal. Why would items be in the modal scope if the controller doesn't put them in it?

Comment: No, problem is not in this, it works, I see template after open document. but I can not see variable inside

Comment: @Darama read the rest of my comment.

Comment: Can you move to chat?

Comment: I can, but I don't want to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138272/discussion-between-darama-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far i understand from your question, It seems you need to display an variable     `$scope.subcategories` from your parent controller `CategoryController`, to your Modal `$fancyModal`..
If i understood correct, just passing parent scope to your modal will resolve it..

```
$fancyModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'public/popupTmpl.html',
    scope: $scope,
    resolve: {
    items: function() {
          return $scope.subcategories;
       }
    }
});
```

Using `scope:$scope` will pass the scope of the controller `CategoryController` to the Modal also. Thus, it will help you to use(pass) all the variables and functions within the `CategoryController`, in the fancyModal also..